# Has someone found a way to upvote their own comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, upvotes

***(Please see edit below before answering)***

If you look at [JavaScript click() - not working more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39847962/1493346) you'll see questions and answers downvoted (harshly, in my opinion, but hey it can be a subjective thing). But what seems curious is the comments underneath them that have been upvoted. All by the same user, all with varying degrees of relevance to the question. One of them, dare I say it, borderline spiteful.

At time of writing, all of this user's comments have been upvoted, nobody else's have. Coincidence? Perhaps this user has someone following them who just upvotes everything they do? Or have they found a way to upvote their own comments?

#### Edit

Some of the comments in that question and its answers have since been removed. Please don't be misled, I have no problem with what's left behind.

Comment: The vastly more likely explanation seems to be that someone read the discussions, sides with the guy, and as a reaction upvoted each of their comments. No?

Comment: _Has someone found a way to upvote their own comments?_ That is found very long ago. That thing is called sock-puppet which I believe is not the case here.

Comment: Probably the question asker who is upvoting the comments.

Comment: A subsequent comment from the asker: "Offtopic - I don't really understand the number of downvotes in this whole thing". One of the upvoted comments was "This is my downvote [to your answer]". So I doubt the asker upvoted that comment.

Comment: OK, then it was someone else from the 56 people who’ve viewed the Q&A so far. It happens regularly, I even do that (upvoting each of one side’s comments) myself in discussions I feel invested in

Comment: I'm trying to be objective, but as I was one of the people who answered and got downvoted by this guy (even though the asker accepted my answer as correct) perhaps I'm failing. It just seemed a bit weird to me but I guess I'll drop it

Comment: I can’t judge who is right and who is wrong in this, but in general: it’ll happen that people criticize you with incorrect arguments, and others incorrectly agree with them. All you can do is calmly present your argument. It won’t always be successful at first - but over time, things often correct themselves as more people read and vote on stuff

Comment: "jQuery doesn't do what you describe."... It is somewhat surprising that you've agreed with the comment but did not fix the answer... And even more interesting you are surprised that comment is upvoted - it seem like you have some other way to suggest improvements to the post - you may want to actually spell it out in this question.

Comment: I haven't yet had time to find the correct fix for that part of my answer (note that it was only a mooted alternative approach to the first, correct part of my answer). I will come back to it when I can. As for the comment, that one you mention is certainly worthy of an upvote. It was some of the subsequent (now deleted) comments being upvoted that surprised me. I've updated my question to point out that the comments I was referring to are now gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Perhaps this user has someone following them who just upvotes everything they do?

This is the most likely cause, though it's probably limited to this question only. The user has a lot of [not upvoted comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502381/jjj?tab=activity&sort=comments).

Unlike [serial voting on posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/295232), serial voting on comments is not forbidden AFAIK. Serial voting on comments does not earn you any reputation or badges (except the [Pundit badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/94/pundit) but you'll need 5 serial voters for that).

Comment: I just tested - Did my 5 Second serial-comment-voting warning go away at a certain rep threshold?

Comment: @RadLexus there seems to be [no such limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/295232).

Comment: Hmm-mm ... after looking at that overview, you must be right. I probably confused it with one of those constraints.

Comment: 5 seconds between *flagging* comments, perhaps?

Comment: @RadLexus you're right it did - it was removed not too long ago: See title on [revision 53](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/164900/53) and the [previous revision](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/164900/52) with that in it...